# reverse greedy algorithm

Tags: graph-theory

I got this reverse greedy algorithm here as below:

First we sort edges of G in decreasing order, as e_1 > e_2　> ... e_m

Then begin with T := G

for i=1,2,...,m

if T-e_i is connected, then T:= T-e_i

end

How do we show the output is a minimum spanning tree?

I want to show it is a spanning tree first, which I know V(T)=V(G), and also if there is any cycle, the edges on cycle will be deleted as after deleting one edge cycle is still connected and therefore we will update graph. So output contains no cycle.

But how do we show it has minimum total weight as well? I can see it is very clear the case, but don't know what is a good way to set up the proof. Can anybody please give me a hand? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the minimum spanning tree $M$ have edges $f_1 > f_2 > \cdots > f_m$. If it is not the same one as the one produced by the above algorithm (let's call it $A$), then there is $k$ such that $e_k \in A \setminus M$, $f_k \in M \setminus A$, and $e_i \in A \cap M$ for all $i < k$. In plain words, $k$ is the index of the first edge that doesn't belong in the minimal tree, but your algorithm would pick it anyway.

Now, take a look at the algorithm. What can you say for $e_k \lesseqqgtr f_k$?

Let me give you an additional hint, for this part only. Your algorithm takes edges by their weight, as long as they don't close cycles. This means that $f_k \not\in \{e_1,\dots,e_k\}$. To see that this is true, just assume the opposite, i.e., $f_k = e_i$ for some $i < k$. Obviously, $f_k = e_i \not\in A$, and you get a contradiction ($f_k = e_i$ closes a cycle; otherwise, your algorithm would pick it). What do you conclude from that, regarding $e_k \lesseqqgtr f_k$?

Do this for all such $k$ and you should have your proof.

Comment: Hmm, thank you Vedran, I need to think about what you said, still feeling a bit confused with what to do. I see it must be true, which is very easy to see from examples or say just intuition, I just don't know how to set up rigorous work to show the result. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @Tian I have added an additional hint, which I believe should help you get the proof by yourself. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Vedran, thank you so much. It is very clear now! I got it. However, I got a little question here. I'm a bit puzzled with the logic on the way you suggested solving this question, would you say this is like proof by contradiction? Because in my notes, I have seen proof such as Greedy algorithm gives maximum spanning tree by showing output is spanning tree first, then it has maximum weight. So I thought the idea for this question must be showing it is a spanning tree first, then show the total weight is minimum. What's your opinion? Thanks again! :)

Comment: @Tian First, there is usually more than one way to prove a statement. For this, I have chosen a proof by contradiction, simply because it's easier (for me) to have something to compare to (i.e., I have the assumed minimum $M$ which I can compare to the tree $A$ produced by the algorithm).

Comment: @Tian Second, I feel that it is quite obvious that $A$ is a spanning tree (it creates a subgruph by removing only those edges that belong to a cycle, so adding any of those removed edges will close a cycle -- isn't that the very definition of a spanning tree?). I may be wrong, because this also depends on the requirements that are imposed on you. In that case, what I wrote in the last parenthesis in this comment should be enough, along with a small explanation why the removed edges close cycles (it is not entirely obvious).

Comment: I agree with you entirely, just I never thought of proof by contradiction, and of course it looks a lot easier. I simply thought I have to directly show it from definitions, and I certainly could see how easy to see the output must be minimum spanning tree. I just wasn't sure how to really write up to show there will by no more cycles and the weight is minimum. It was easy to see the output certainly got same vertex set as original graph. Thanks again for your kind explanation!

Comment: @VedranŠego The algorithm does not 'take edges by their weight, as long as they don't close cycles'. It starts with the full set of edges and keeps removing edges by weight until the graph is connected. I think you contradiction on $f_k \not\in \{e_1,\dots,e_k\}$ will not work due to this.

Comment: @user13987 This was a clumsy expression on my part. It *chooses* the edges by their weight and removes them, which means that those that remain are a) those that don't form cycles, and b) (indirectly) also chosen by weight (because they were not removed, which is chosen by weight). The rest of the statements are still correct. The one that you refer to simply comes from the assumption that $f_k \in M \setminus A$, i.e., $f_k \not\in A$. But, $e_i \in M \cap A$, also by assumption, which means that $e_i \in A$.